# How do you store and access session data in a rack based application

Tags: ruby, rack

How do you store and access session data in a rack based application. I am building a rack based application in ruby, i need to store data in session how do I do it?

Comment: Have a look at http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Session/Cookie.html and http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Session/Pool.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quite an open question. Do you want to store data server side or client side? In the first case, you can store data in cookies:

```
def call
    status, headers, body = @app.call(env)

    response = Rack::Response.new body, status, headers

    response.set_cookie("foo", {:value => "bar", :path => "/", :expires => Time.now+24*60*60})
    response.finish
end
```

In the latter case, you you'll probably want to store it in a database (you can use ActiveRecord or other object mappers), or just a plain text file.

TL;DR: Look at frameworks for creating and storing sessions.

Comment: does rack provide any option to store the session server side

Comment: No. If you want to do this, best is to use a framework (sinatra is simple, but can do stuff for you e.g.)

Comment: It seems that Rack::Session::Pool does this.